# Google API Spreadsheets get hangs forever after Chrome 67 update

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-api, get, spreadsheet

When using Google API gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get, the browser hangs indefinitely. Neither the success or error handler on the promise are resolved.

This only started after updating to Chrome 67, which has been validated on multiple machines using the same script and the same spreadsheet being requested.  Still works for 66, 65 etc. Also works with Firefox and Edge. Does't seem to work with Internet Explorer for a different reason in the API code.

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({
  spreadsheetId: sheetId,
  ranges: ['Sheet1!A1:I','Sheet2!A1:J', 'Sheet3!A1:I', 'Sheet4!A1:B'],
  includeGridData: true,
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Data loaded!")
  var range = response.result;

  if (range.sheets.length > 0) {      
    doStuff();
  } else {
    appendPre('No data found.');
  }
}, function(response) {
    console.log("Error!")
    appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
});
```

I would expect to see from this code at a minimum a log that says 'Data Loaded' or 'Error', but it just never happens.

I did notice there seems to be some sort of a correlation between either A. the size of the request, or B. the empty rows that are getting included in the request.

The only thing the console says is:

[Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 537ms cb=gapi.loaded_0:123

[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 754ms

The size of the request is 1 MB, the content is 62.3 MB.

One other interesting thing which I hope isn't a red herring, when Firefox displayed the response data from the request, there is a message that says:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data while reading object contents at line 29170 column 21 of the JSON data"

When you look at the response, it ends abruptly in the middle of the code. It leads me to believe that yes, the response is so big that it just ends - and that maybe Firefox is able to handle this strangeness, but the new version of chrome can't.

Even though I get a status code 200 for the request in Chrome, the response is completely blank - as in just white - no message at all.

It seems I might be able to solve this by breaking it into multiple smaller requests instead, but I didn't have to do that before so just want to make sure I'm not coding around a bug.

My question is:
Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Has anyone had issues with size of the requests before?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've broken it up into multiple requests. It does indeed seem to be directly related to size. The second sheet I get is the biggest, and when that request is over 1 KB / content ~50 MB it starts to fail..

Comment: I also tried making batch requests, which I was excited about, but unfortunately ran into the same issue, which was surprising given I was using batch.then() which I thought broke it into separate network requests.  You can read more here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch.

If anyone needs to solve this issue immediately, I just came up with a funny solution where I create an array of my requests, and each request, once successful, calls the next one array item.  Then, I just make each request small enough that it doesn't fail. Not optimal, but works.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I'm seeing similar behaviour

Comment: I haven't tested any of the new versions of Chrome, but basically I ended up doing this:

1. Do a spreadsheets.values.get, that way I can see how many rows are in that sheet without it being a heavy request
2. Now, I build an array (requests) of spreadsheets.get as promises.
3. Then I execute all the promises with a Promises.all()
4. Then I just concat the results.
This works for my specific situation because I'm fairly certain 3,000 rows will never be too big, but I'm assuming it would break if the volume of your data in those rows is highly variable.

Comment: the comments on this seem to have solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488562/google-apis-sheets-v4-sheetsservice-execute-freezes-application-in-dotnet-mono?noredirect=1#comment91920619_52488562