# Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService Execute freezes application in dotnet Mono

Tags: c#, mono, google-sheets-api

I've been using the GoogleSheets API from a C# application in windows without problem for quite a while.

When I port this program to Linux, and run using Mono, it freezes regularly at "Execute" for Spreadsheets.Get OR BatchUpdate.

```
  SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
  var gotSS = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);   // <<< freezes HERE
...
  var vbur = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(buvr, spreadsheetId);  // <<< OR freezes HERE
```

It doesn't just get stuck and not return - all threads in the application freeze.

What could be the cause?

The stacktrace for that thread shows:

> "unnamed thread"  at  <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait
>   (int,System.Threading.CancellationToken) [0x00141] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait
>   (int,System.Threading.CancellationToken) [0x0002d] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait
>   (int,System.Threading.CancellationToken) [0x00069] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<TResult_REF>.GetResultCore (bool)
>   [0x00008] in <b78dcefd6c184245be8bf4a1e52466d9>:0   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result () [0x0000f] in
>   :0   at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1<TResponse_REF>.Execute ()
>   [0x0000b] in <1587d07172024990b6af5b790c2a559c>:0   at
>   myFuncs.GCMupdates.sendToGoogleSheets
>   (myFuncs.clsPositionManager/HistSummaryData,myFuncs.clsPositionManager/Position2HistData,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2,double,double,double,double,double,System.Collections.Generic.List`1)
>   [0x00236] in <1791c5302f4a454b8cf7412b7f799253>:0   at
>   myFuncs.GCMupdates.sendNotification
>   (myFuncs.clsPositionManager/HistSummaryData,double,myFuncs.clsPositionManager/Position2HistData,myFuncs.subLog)
>   [0x009c3] in <1791c5302f4a454b8cf7412b7f799253>:0   at
>   Master.MainForm.UpdateDets
>   (myFuncs.clsPositionManager/HistSummaryData,int,int,double,myFuncs.clsPositionManager/Position2HistData,myFuncs.subLog)
>   [0x0063e] in <4860a2c0b9a848eeab8026906aeac5a8>:0   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke)
>   .runtime_invoke_void__this___object_int_int_double_object_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006b] in
>   <4860a2c0b9a848eeab8026906aeac5a8>:0   at  <0xffffffff>   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>   [0x0000c] in :0   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke
>   (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
>   [0x0003b] in :0   at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (object,object[]) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (object[]) [0x000e7] in
>   :0   at
>   System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (object[]) [0x00008] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (object[]) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIDriverSupport.ExecutionCallback
>   (System.Windows.Forms.AsyncMethodData) [0x00007] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIDriverSupport.ExecutionCallbackInContext
>   (object) [0x00027] in <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
>   [0x00071] in :0   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object)
>   [0x0002b] in :0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIDriverSupport.ExecuteClientMessage
>   (System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle) [0x00028] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetMessage
>   (object,System.Windows.Forms.MSG&,intptr,int,int) [0x01762] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetMessage
>   (object,System.Windows.Forms.MSG&,intptr,int,int) [0x00000] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop
>   (bool,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [0x0034e] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run
>   (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [0x00011] in
>   <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form)
>   [0x00006] in <951cc200450d41168b6f8c8543d9b41e>:0   at
>   Master.Program.Main (string[]) [0x00137] in
>   <4860a2c0b9a848eeab8026906aeac5a8>:0   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   [0x0004e] in <4860a2c0b9a848eeab8026906aeac5a8>:0

Comment: Perform a thread dump and review the stack results

Comment: how do you do that for a frozen application?

Comment: using kill -QUIT $PID I assume, I've added the output above

Comment: It appears to be deadlocked on the UI thread, try performing the network based operations (sendToGoogleSheets) on a background thread (via new Thread or Task.Run)

Comment: that seems to have worked - hasn't crashed for quite a while now.
Any idea why that would cause a problem on Linux but not Windows?

Comment: Well, on Windows you should be doing this also. Windows.Forms via the Mono project is old/deprecated/etc... so there is that, but also you are running X11 and as ALL other GUIs, you should never block the UI thread's message pump and some OSs do not even allow network activity to be performed in the UI/Main thread...